# Export whole html page to pdf using JSPdf generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, jspdf

I have already added these js file to my aspx page. But i still couldn't able to get pdf file of my table data. the generated pdf is blank.i need all table data to that generated pdf .please if any one know how to do this?

```
 <script src="../Script/jspdf.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/Blob.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/deflate.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/adler32cs.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/base64.js"></script>
        <script src="../Script/sprintf.js"></script>
```

// Here is my aspx table or div content:

```
<div id="divReport" style="display: none">

            <input type="button" id="btnSavePdf" value="Save as Pdf" />
                   <table id="example">
                <tr id="trProject">
                    <td><span>Project :</span></td>
                    <td><span id="spanProject" runat="server"></span></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><span>Total Number of Employee :</span></td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="spanTotalEmp" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"  ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Total Number of Hours :</span></td>
                    <td>

                         <asp:Label ID="spanTotalHours" runat="server" name="_name2" EnableViewState="false"  ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

// Below is my Javascript button onclick code:

```
$('#btnSavePdf').click(function () {

            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
            var source = $('#divReport').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            doc.fromHTML(
                source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                0.5,    // x coord
                0.5,    // y coord
                {
                    'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });

            doc.output('dataurl');
```

Comment: Do you want to render the entire html page (as title suggests) or just the table (as your question suggests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to render the table only instead of the entire page. You can do this using the [HTML table export jQuery plugin](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php#). This is what your HTML would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="tableExport.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="example">
   <!-- rows here -->
</table>    
<a href="#" onclick ="$('#example').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">As PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks buddy!!! it's working but can you please tell me how to resize or customize table layout because generated pdf overwrite the columns of table.

Comment: @vivek did you find re-size or customize table layout solution i have applied above code but it not in well format with spaces

Comment: @MohammadFaizankhan how i add border in printed table pdf. please see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469939/html-tabel-rendering-to-pdf-content-in-pdf-not-tabel-format

Comment: @Frank Rem - How would i suppose to get entire HTML content. I am able to save only visible contents

Answer (score 1):

That `style="display:none"` would prevent it from rendering, thus you get a blank page.

That said, i think you're using quite old templates, cause `sprintf.js` and `base64.js` were removed something like three years ago. You should just need to include one of the files available on the `dist` folder.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/dist

Here you have a working fromHTML table example using the latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/dGLmr/7/