# Html to pdf Jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

When I'm converting my html div to pdf using Jspdf library the  generated pdf
is not showing the whole content of mydiv.It only shows little html but not complete div. What I am missing in this ?

```
<button id="b2">Export to pdf</button>
<script>

var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
$('#b2').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#mydiv').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});


</script>
```

Comment: Making a snippet or jsfiddle showing your problem would make it easier for you to get help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23540022/4229270
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22992070/4229270

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do:

- Check if your IDs are correct: `#editor` for the specialElementHandlers and `#mydiv` in the click function?
- Check the Javascript console for errors
- Check [examples like this](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/from-html.js) or [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184659/cannot-make-pdf-from-html-div-by-jspdf/22992070#22992070) to find any errors